# neo4jclient fails to authenticate against neo4j database when TransactionalGraphClient is used

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

The following C# code implementing neo4jclient connects to the database correctly:

```
static readonly string dbConnection = "http://user:pass@localhost:7474/db/data";
GraphClient neoClient = new GraphClient(new Uri(dbConnection));
```

However the same code fails when the client is cast as transactional.

```
static readonly string dbConnection = "http://user:pass@localhost:7474/db/data";
ITransactionalGraphClient neoClient = new GraphClient(new Uri(dbConnection));
```

with the error

```
The response status was: 401 Unauthorized

The response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized",
    "message" : "No authentication header supplied."
  } ]
}
```

I need to use transactions, is there a reason for this behavior or a way to get around it?

UPDATE: I've discovered that the initial database connection actually does work. The exception is thrown from my first Cypher query, so I've posted that query here as well in case that's the problem.

```
public void AddNode(NodeClass node)
{
    using (var transaction = neoClient.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var paramaters = new
        {
            Id = node.Id,
            Name = node.Name,
            ...
        };

        neoClient.Cypher
           .Create("(x:NodeLabel {paramaters})")
           .WithParam("paramaters", paramaters)
           .ExecuteWithoutResults();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the cast has anything to do at all? What happens if you first instantiate it with the first code block you posted and then you cast it to `ITransactionalGraphClient`?

Comment: I tried that originally, and it does the same thing. I've formatted the code here with the immediate cast just for readability.

Comment: Then the cast has nothing to do at all, revise the credentials.

Comment: Credentials are correct, and work correctly for non-transactional cypher queries. See update.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/issues/96

Comment: A bug known for nearly 2 years, in a basic use case, in an actively developed project, and it still hasn't been fixed?! This and the lack of good documentation is really making me think twice about using neo4jclient over the official neo4j .NET driver. Anyway thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your connection to be:

`new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "user", "pass");`

you will connect and execute your queries absolutely fine.

In terms of that case not being marked as fixed - that's mainly down to the fact that I usually wait for the bug reporter to mark it as so, but I probably should have a cleanup - in fact I have been, but haven't got there yet.

From a POV of the documentation being lacking - again I can only apologise. This is mostly down to the fact that unfortunately I have to work to live, and sometimes I feel I just want to relax when I get home :-o

Comment: Oh wow, it was that easy all along. I'm quite happy I don't have to use the clunky manual IHttpClient anymore, thanks so much!
Since GitHub doesn't allow pull requests for wiki pages, is there any other way individuals can contribute to neo4jclient documentation?

Comment: I thought you could just edit them. Maybe I'll look at switching it to a form Github does allow pull requests for